# Oriya font to be displayed in Android app (Lenovo K3)

Tags: android, android-typeface

I want to display certain text in Oriya font in my android app. There is no default support in android for Oriya language. I tried different ttf files for Oriya font but not able to display the content. Can anyone help me in this?
I have tried the following code keeping the **oriya.ttf** file in my assets folder.

```
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/oriya.ttf");
        tvSoft.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Comment: Please add some snippet of the code what you tried. We are not here to do your homework

Comment: so using the code you posted, did you see the text with the default Android font instead of Oriya?

Comment: I am just seeing boxes instead of any text.

Comment: I am facing this issue only in lenovo K3. In other devices it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change font in android this is the best solution: 
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy